# PHP function "resize" and "fit" do not work

Tags: php

I'm using PHP image intervention in my remote VPS server. Code works correctly. Function `text()` works properly. I have a problem with method `resize()` and the `fit()`.

I'm looking forward to your help

function `text()` working

[image]

function `resize()` not working

[image]

Comment: Please add your code as text to your question (and pay attention to [code formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)). There are [many good reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557), why images of code are not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php function:

```
imagecopyresized ( resource $dst_image , resource $src_image , int $dst_x , int $dst_y , int $src_x , int $src_y , int $dst_w , int $dst_h , int $src_w , int $src_h ) : bool
```

to check if the former part is working as expected or even use it as final solution